# MKMapKit error: MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, mkannotation, mapkit

What this error means?

```
MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

It happens, when I am trying add new MKAnnotation to the MKMapView.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

> Problem has been: I was generating random coords in some area. So, my number has mistaken data type. Not "100." (CGFloat), but "100" (NSUInteger). So 100/1000 was 0, not 0.1 (100./1000). After this bad math system returns coords that never exists on Earth.